# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING

Tags: php, sendmail, html-email

I am trying to retrieve data from database and show that data in the table header in the text mail function,but i am getting an error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

can anyone tell how to fix this error

my code :

```
 $text_mail.= "<table style='margin:0px'>
    <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Networkname </th>
    <th>Mcc</th>
    <th>Mnc</th> 
    <th>Oldprice </th>      
    <th>Newprice </th>      
    <th>Comments </th>  
     <?php  


      $dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'xxxx';
$dbPassword = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$dbDatabase = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

    $ColumnNames = mysql_query('select clientid from client_list ORDER BY `clientid` ASC') or die('mysql error');       
    $columnArray=array();
    $i=0;       
    while($data3=mysql_fetch_array($ColumnNames))
    {
        $columnArray[]=$data3[0];

            echo '<th style='width:67px;' class='. $columnArray[$i] .' >" . $columnArray[$i] . " 
                </th>';

            echo'<th></th>';


    $i++;   
            }

    ?>  

    </tr>";
```

Comment: Hope its a mistake while posting the code but you forgot to close the <th>Comments </th>";

Comment: The syntax highlighting is telling.

Answer (score 0):

correct these:

```
$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die (\"Unable to connect to Database Server.\");
mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die (\"Could not select database.\");
```

or use single quotes

Answer (score 0):

if this is not a typo error then you need to add ending " (double quote) after

change

```
    $text_mail.= "<table style='margin:0px'>
    <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Networkname </th>
    <th>Mcc</th>
    <th>Mnc</th> 
    <th>Oldprice </th>      
    <th>Newprice </th>      
    <th>Comments </th>

to 

$text_mail.= "<table style='margin:0px'>
<tr>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Networkname </th>
<th>Mcc</th>
<th>Mnc</th> 
<th>Oldprice </th>      
<th>Newprice </th>      
<th>Comments </th> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<?php` tag as you are already in php

Answer (score 0):

1. if this is not a typo error then you need to add ending " (double quote) after
2. Remove php tag after ending .
   change

   $text_mail.= "
       
       Country
       Networkname 
       Mcc
       Mnc 
       Oldprice 
       Newprice 
       Comments

to

```
$text_mail.= "<table style='margin:0px'>
<tr>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Networkname </th>
<th>Mcc</th>
<th>Mnc</th> 
<th>Oldprice </th>      
<th>Newprice </th>      
<th>Comments </th> ";
```